# Using data from large csv file in Paraview

Tags: python, csv, paraview

The closest question I could find to this issue is [How to store a vector field with VTK? C++, VTKWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937139/how-to-store-a-vector-field-with-vtk-c-vtkwriter)

Basically I have a large csv file which is comprised of rows representing each timestep and columns representing the properties of a large number of particles (without headers). Essentially the columns go as t, x1, x2, ..., y1, y2, ..., z1, z2, ... and I am trying to use paraview to make sense of this. It is impractical to do this via the table to points filter in the GUI and was wondering if there was another way to do it?

The only solution I can think of is to slice the dataframe and use the python interface with a loop. I was wondering if there was a way through the GUI or if it makes more sense to convert to a vtk file? I am new to paraview and wish to know the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is by using a Python Programmable Source.

Using Python (eg. with numpy) it would be quite easy to reader the data and provide it to paraview timestep by timestep.

See some Programmable Source examples here :
https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Python_Programmable_Filter

If you have no experience with the VTK pipeline, this will not be a trivial task.